# On my initial ESTA application I was transiting through the US. However now my travel plans have changed and I'm staying in the US. Help?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, change-purpose-of-travel

I initially applied for an ESTA in November, and I was going to travel through the US to Costa Rica - and stated this on my application.

However, I never actually ended up travelling to the US or Costa Rica, and I stayed in England.

But now I am travelling to the US, and staying in the US, not transiting through.

Do I need to update my ESTA travel plans? And if I update my ESTA, does it need to be reviewed again, and how long does this take?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Asked the CBP about this a while ago, and you don't need a new ESTA, but should update the details in your current ESTA that can be updated, if any (don't know how it works if you selected transit, but otherwise several details, such as what address you're staying at, can be edited).

At most airports you can now use a kiosk (*automated passport control*) instead of filling out the blue form. The kiosk will ask in what status you're seeking admission (WB for business, WT for tourism).

Such situations are common, so the officers are used to it. You'll be fine!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - however, unfortunately I don't have the option to edit/update my address as I didn't input an address to start with. The only option I have is to update my email address. // As the question regarding travelling in transit to the US is a 'Yes/No' question - I'm worried that my ESTA is not valid - and I'm due to travel in a few days time, and I'm unsure as to what to do.

Comment: @James If E-Mail is all you can update, then simply leave it be. The address and other things will be supplied to the CBP through the advance passenger processing (API) performed at online check-in, and your ESTA remains valid

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I do have a valid ESTA which I used for transit, but this time I’m going to stay in the US. On the ESTA you can only change your e-Mail, if you said you were going to transit at the time you applied for it. However I called the border control and they told me I could reuse that ESTA anyways as long as I had the new address where I would be staying with me.
Hope that helps :)